# Android shell commands not working (adb Ubuntu)

Tags: android, adb

```
adb sentevent
adb input event
```

Above event are not working. But 'adb getevent' works properly. while using input tap the android os restarts, and no response while using adb sentevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please turn off the developers option, then the input tap event works without restart.